# MAUI Assembly - Runtime values different

Tags: c#, maui

Very frustrated with MAUI assembly. I have built a small assembly and test project, when debugging and running test cases, everything is as expected. If I build (Debug or Release) and put the assembly in my app I get different responses.

In the image you can see on the left , the test case from the assembly returning 4 orders which is correct but on the right (in app with debug assembly) results are 0. All this method is doing is calling a webservice, de-serialising a response into Order object

In the App SubAdminArea matches that of the test case. Any help would be great

[image]

**EDIT**
I have added a default object to return from the WebService all. It simply sets the value of Delivery Note to the json value. If an error is caught, the error is appended to the delivery note.

**Issue**
Test case again works fine, i can see the new object and delivery note set. When i try in app Delivery Note is null. Its as if the code is refusing to set values. Its very weird.

All working in test cases and in Postman. Just refusing to work from assembly

[image]

[image]

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken?  There is almost nothing useful we can tell you based on what you've posted.

Comment: Ive tried Debug and Release versions of the assembly. Clearing out cache (deleting old assembly). Other than that, what can i do?  The test project is calling the method and it works fine but when i call it from my app, i dont get results.

There is little information out there on the Maui Class library type and i expect few are using it. I have 3 apps which make up one solution so i need a good way to manage changes and updated.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image.  Have you stepped through your library code in the debugger in both scenarios to see how they are behaving differently?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I have a HasInternetConnection() which checks for access to the internet on the device.

```
public static bool HasInternetConnection()
 {
     if (Connectivity.Current.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
         return true;

     return false;
 }
```

When i first created the assembly, i ran into trouble with this method even though i have UseMaui=true and UseMauiEssentials=true in the project.cs file. With this in mind, i changed how i checked for an internet connection to CheckForInternetConenction() which works fine.

```
private static ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishRequest), request);
        evt.WaitOne();
        return request.HaveResponse;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private static void FinishRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
    evt.Set();
}
```

Turns out CheckForInternetConenction() wont run on mobile devices, throws and error and i dont get any results. HasInternetConnect() works fine in Mobile apps and not within the assembly.

**New Code**

```
private static ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);

 public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
 {
     try
     {
         if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.Unknown)
         {
             HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
             request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
             request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishRequest), request);
             evt.WaitOne();
             return request.HaveResponse;
         }
         else
         {
             if (Connectivity.Current.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
                 return true;
         }

     }
     catch
     {
         return false;
     }

     return false;
 }

 private static void FinishRequest(IAsyncResult result)
 {
     HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
     evt.Set();
 }
```

More importantly the following line to allow the code to work in both places

```
if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.Unknown)
```

Thanks for looking, hope it helps someone